# How to replace a world if word is exist otherwise append a word in the end of line using sed

Tags: bash, shell

How to replace a world if word is exist otherwise append a word in the end of line using sed 
example:

> case 1:
>   Before replace if exist yzz :

```
 my name is xyz
    my father name is yzz
    i live at wert
```

> After replace if yzz exist

```
 my name is xyz
 my father name is yzzsst
 i live at wert
```

> case 2:
>   Before replace if not exist yzz

```
my name is xyz
my father name is 
i live at wert
```

> After replace

```
my name is xyz
my father name is yzzsst
i live at wert
```

Comment: Do you want this to happen only in 2nd line?

Comment: yes only in second line

Answer (score 0):

I would rather do it with `awk` with that You can do it like:

```
awk '/father name is WHATEVER/ {gsub(/WHATEVER/,"REPLACEMENT"); print ; next }
     /father name is$/ {print $0 " REPLACEMENT" ; next }
     {print}' INPUTFILE
```

The first condition checks if the name is present, replaces and prints, and skips more actions for this line. The next condition checks if the line ends with `name is` and if so prints it and appends `REPLACEMENT`. Lastly every other line gets printed.

With (GNU)`sed` you can try something like:

```
sed -n '/my father/!p; /my father/s/\( NAME$\)\|\($\)/ REPLACEDNAME/p'
```

But it's just a quick "hack": by default do not print anything (`-n`), but if the line does not match `my father` than print it, otherwise check if `NAME` is present at the and of line and replaces this or if it wasn't present appends the `REPLACEDNAME`.

Answer (score 0):

You may use this `awk` that will work for both the cases:

```
awk 'NR==2{sub(/( *yzz *)?$/, " yzzst")} 1' file
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this :

```
$ echo "$response" | sed -E "3 s/(.*)( [a-zA-Z]+ *$)/\1 DUDETRUSTME/g"

my name is xyz
    my father name is DUDETRUSTME
    i live at wert
```

Im assuming you want to replace the third line, but you can change that 3 for whatever number you like, or even a range. Also I assumed your target word ( in this case *yzz* ) is not fixed but it might be anything.

Comment: IMO it will replace `^my father name is$` with `my father name DUDETRUSTME`. Also in this case the ending `g` flag is not needed.